# Magento 2 - Event being triggered multiple times in one request

Tags: magento, magento2

I have created an Observer to monitor this event in Magento 2 `newsletter_subscriber_save_after`. I am lost and not sure how to proceed with this because this event is getting fired 3 times.

The purpose of the observer is to connect to an API and send an email when a user is added to the newsletter. Since the event is firing 3 times, so will the observer. This means 3 calls are made to the API and the only workaround was to create a stop at the API to prevent 3 emails being sent out. That is not the best solution.

Why is Magento 3 firing 3 events for one request? Is there a workaround?

Another awful issue is that if a user is unsubscribing the first two event firing has the user as Subscribed and only the 3rd event the user is then set to Unsubscribed? I am confused. I am have read about using a Plugin instead, but I really want to concentrate this module around Observers. Is Observer this unreliable?

I am new to Magento, but this makes me wonder if I am looking at it the wrong way.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you found solutions for this ? i am also getting this event "sales_order_save_before" call 2 times

Comment: No! I have not find any solution and there is just how Magento works. However, there is a way to prevent it from having the observer react more than once, but it requires using the Registry to log the first call and skip any proceeding calls. I plan on going back to working on that module again next week.